# Weird dot on screen that captures all input

Tags: touchscreen, htc-one

Forgive me for the unclear title. Some time ago, my HTC M8, which is rooted and runs on a [Venom ROM](http://venomroms.com/) showed something weird. Firstly, in the Google Maps App a mysterious blue dot appeared, that captures the screen completely and makes it impossible to quit or use the application. It looks like this (I could make a screenshot)

[image]
[image]

When this happens in Maps, the only thing I can do is a hard restart with `Power`+`Volume Up`.

Since I have seen this occasionally in the camera app as well, I suspect it is not a bug of Maps itself. I know that the Venom ROM is not standard but maybe this is connected to some setting and anyone has seen this. Btw, the Venom ran smoothly for almost 3 years now.

**Question:** Has someone a clue what this could be and how I can get rid of it?

Comment: Potentially malwares related. Did you recently install any app ? Go check your apps list if there are some apps that seem unusual.

Comment: I'm very cautious with installing new apps. I have my set of applications and did not install anything new (or potentially untrustworthy). I know that making a clean install of the OS is a final solution, but I hoped someone came across this issue.

Comment: Did you check the apps list?

Comment: Yes, nothing which looks even remotely suspicious. I can identify every app.

Comment: What about background processes and services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question in [this xda thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/htc-one-m8/general/white-dot-mouse-pointer-m8-t3524318). What I experience is the white dot that can be switched on in the developer options, although there, I have never turned it on.

I guess my only solution is to either install a new ROM or return to stock :(